# Spacing between Action bar icon and Title.

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ABS for backwards compatibility. In one of my activities, I'm using Action Bar tabs which appear before custom view (in landscape) in action bar so I can't use that. So i'm using Action bar title. So in short, my question is how do I increase the spacing between the title and the icon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I added some spacing like this:

```
actionBar.setTitle("  " + myTitle);
```

I don't think it should be done this way but I've searched a lot I couldn't find any solution for this without using custom view which I can't because I'm using AB tabs.

So if anyone else has a better (cleaner) solution, do answer. For others, this works better than anything else I tried.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Adding these link in **Toolbar** declaration in xml file.

```
app:contentInsetLeft="16dp"
app:contentInsetStart="16dp"
app:contentInsetEnd="16dp"
app:titleMarginStart="32dp"
```

Pay attention at the app prefix. This worked for me with **Android 4.4.2** and **Android 5.1**.